# Вывод переменной $_SESSION

Tags: php

Не выводиться имя юнита, что делать? 
У юзера есть свой юнит , этот юнит находить в таблице с паролем и логином, как его оттуда вытянуть?

**Страница юзера:**

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "Добро пожаловать, ".$_SESSION['username']."!";
echo "Твой Бакуган, ".$_SESSION['bakugan']."!";
?>
```

**И проверка входа:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$host = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db_name = "";
$tbl_name = "";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT `username`,`bakugan` FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:login_success.php");
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['bakugan'] = $bakugan;

}
else{  
echo "Неверный логин или Пароль";
}
```

P.S. knes , sorry последний тупой вопрос)))

Comment: Атака клонов? =)

Comment: Неее, я поменял имя))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
and password='$password'"; /* пароль в открытом виде хранится? О_о  */

$_SESSION['bakugan'] = $bakugan; /* Переменная бакуган не задана. Вы извлекаете имя бакугана из БД, но не присваиваете какой-то левой переменной бакуган значения. Нехорошо.
Правильно так:*/

if($count==1) {
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_object($result);
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:login_success.php");
$_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo->username;
$_SESSION['bakugan'] = $userinfo->bakugan;

}
?>
```